# Why do Windows & Ubuntu have similar shell commands?

Tags: command-line, bash, windows, history-of-ubuntu

Ubuntu has a bash (Bourne Again SHell) whereas Windows has it's proprietary shell. According to my research there is no name for the language used for shell scripting in Windows/Ubuntu. It's just called shell scripting.

Why do Windows & Ubuntu shells understand the same commands such as : `ls`, `mkdir`, `rmdir`, `mount` and so on?

Is there some sort of lingua franca for shell scripting? If so, please give me more details.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unix_commands - look for when these commands first appeared, and check when Windows and GNU first appeared. These commands aren't part of bash - they are external utilities, so which shell is used is irrelevant.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure `ls` is supported by Powershell, not `cmd.exe`. And that's because the creators of Powershell put in some effort to add aliases for common Unix commands so that Unix users would be more comfortable. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347739.aspx

Comment: The Wikipedia article on DOS, might shed some light on this. Quote: "DOS instead ran on Intel 8086 16-bit processors. Starting with MS-DOS 1.28 and PC DOS 2.0 the operating system incorporated various features inspired from Xenix, Microsoft's variant of Unix." So Unix is, up to a point, a forefather to MS-DOS.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS

Comment: @teodom Indeed. A hierarchical file system (backslash vs slash separated though), some associated commands like `mkdir`, `rmdir`, `cd`, redirections `<`, `>`, `>>` and pipelines `|`  were all obviously borrowed from Unix.

Comment: @muru: In fact, *both* the Unix *and* the DOS commands are actually just aliases to the *real* PowerShell commands, which are named according to a standardized `Action-Object` structure, composed of a set of also standardized actions and objects. For example, both `ls` and `dir` are aliases for `Get-ChildItem` (which additionally has the alias `gci`), `mkdir` and `md` are actually `New-Item` (which can actually create much more than just directories, owing to PowerShell's object-based approach), and so on.

Comment: Also look at CPM, VMS, JCL.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The Windows `cmd.exe` does not support `ls`, `mount`, etc., unless you installed these yourself and added them to the `%PATH%` (via Cygwin, MinGW, [Subsystem for Unix-based Applications (SUA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732759.aspx) or something else). *Powershell* does. And that's because Powershell has these as aliases to standard Powershell commands, so that Unix users can be more comfortable. See the list of [Compatibility Aliases  in Powershell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347739.aspx). Windows does have [`rmdir`, `mkdir`, etc.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx), but these, of course, don't support the same option syntax that you'd find on Ubuntu.

In Ubuntu, these have nothing to do with Bash. They are all external commands. There are standards for such utilities. [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) is the most notable (see the list of [POSIX-mandated utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html)), and [Linux Standard Base (LSB)](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb) is another that's important for Linux systems (which is mostly based on POSIX, but has [some additions](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/command.html#CMDUTIL)). The ones on Ubuntu are mostly provided by [GNU](http://www.gnu.org), and GNU utilities often have more features than the base required by POSIX.

POSIX also defines [the shell language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) that you mentioned (which is substantially different from the one in [`cmd.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490954.aspx)). It is derived from [the Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)'s syntax. Bash (now you know what the *Bourne again* refers to), also from GNU, also adds features on top, but can behave in a POSIX-compliant manner when required. The POSIX language is what you'd expect to get with `sh`. `bash`, `ksh`, `ash`, `dash`, `zsh` all use *that* language, with enhancements. `csh` is in a (nightmare) world of its own, and `tcsh` enhances `csh`.

To understand a bit more, look into the history of Unix and [Unix-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) systems. Unix pre-dates Windows by over a decade, and these utilities first appeared in Unix.

Windows was, at one time, POSIX-compliant, since the US government required it for OSes used by government agencies (that's when they added [the Services for Unix (SFU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX), from which came the SUA mentioned in the first paragraph). But that requirement was scrapped, and subsequently, SUA was dropped.

Related:

- [Evolution of Operating systems from Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3196/70524)
- [Were all Unix commands re-written in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85189/70524)
- [Is Linux a Unix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4091/70524)
- [What does it mean to be “sh compatible”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145522/70524)

(Note the common part of these posts - they are all on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com), and tagged [history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) - you might find browsing through that tag very informative.)

Comment: AFAIK, `rmdir` (along with `mkdir` and `cd / chdir`) are native `command.com` builtins since MS-DOS 2.0 (there was no hierarchy in the DOS file system before)

Comment: @jlliagre Ah, yes. I always thought the command was `rd`.

Comment: `rd` was a shortcut, `md` too.

Comment: This is what I've got from reading your answer and skimming through links provided from others: These command/utilities have first appeared in the past on various different systems. Over time most of them have been integrated into Ubuntu and some of them into Windows. Windows however decided to do things their own way and create their own version of these utilities. Over time Windows decided to add aliases to their own shell commands so that linux users can use commands that on the surface appear the same as on their systems  but underneath they're translated to windows commands

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer that's a good tl;dr version.

Comment: One more thing about shell scripting though: Various linux distros will have different shells like `sh` `bash` `csh` `tcsh` `ksh` and they all have their own shell scripting syntax according to my research. You've mentioned POSIX shell command language standard but I'm confused how does that relate to each of the shells I mentioned since they all have different scripting syntax ? Also as an aside to be extra sure - Am I right that Windows does not obey POSIX standard ?

Comment: The POSIX language is what you'd expect to get with `sh`. `bash`, `ksh`, `ash`, `dash`, `zsh` all use *that* language, with enhancements. `csh` is in a (nightmare) world of its own, and `tcsh` enhances `csh`. Windows did, at one time, obey POSIX, since the US government required it for OSes used by government agencies (that's where the SUA came from). But that requirement was scrapped, and subsequently, SUA was dropped.

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer another U&L post you will find interesting: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145522/70524

Comment: A quick clarification re "They are all external commands." - firstly, some shell commands are fundamentally internal to the shell (manipulating the environment it controls), such as `cd` and `exit`; secondly, most modern shells will have built-in implementations of many of the simplest utilities, such as `test`/`[`. Even with a minimal shell, you can traverse a broken environment using sequences such as `cd /etc; pwd; echo *`

Comment: @IMSoP And on the other extreme, we have busybox.

Comment: Your "POSIX compliant" paragraph implies that this feature of Windows began with SFU, added in Windows 2000, but Windows NT was POSIX.1 — and *only* POSIX.1, not POSIX.2, nor POSIX.1c, nor POSIX.1-2000, etc. — compliant [from the start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_POSIX_subsystem).

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

Linux is a system based on the UNIX model, as invented by Dennis Ritchie and Ken Thompson.

Windows/DOS is a cheap knockoff of a system called CP/M which was popular in the 1970's on those old computers you plugged on a TV, this system in turn was a cheap knockoff of the early UNIX systems from the late 60's / early 70's.

Comment: While there's some truth to your answer, it's way too oversimplified to be useful. (And we used monitors or terminals with CP/M - not TVs ;)   )  When I'm trying to figure out some obscure bash or sed command, I sometimes think back to those days when the OS hardly did anything for you, but it was easy to do - and I never ran out of memory on a 64k machine.